# How many bikes are there if "a" bike is used in "both" tours or "each" tour

Tags: articles, phrase-request

I don't really understand about articles.

If I say "You can use a bicycle in both of the tours," does it mean that I offer the same bike in the two tours?

How can I say when I want to mean "You can use a bike in this tour (You can borrow a bike), and the same service is offered in the other tour, too"?

Comment: _A bicycle_ doesn't specify which one, so it doesn't mean that. You could say "Cycle hire is available for both tours".

Comment: @KateBunting Oh, I see! So, "a bicycle" there doesn't always mean only one bike, does it? Thank you very much!!

Comment: What is the source of the quote, please.  When you quote a phrase you should always give the details.

Comment: @JamesK I see! This time I was to make a sentence by myself. But I will bear that in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The indefinite article "a" is non-specific, so "a bicycle" doesn't mean any specific bike.

"You can use a bicycle" sounds very open-ended - it could mean the person can use their own bike, or any bike that they can obtain. If you want it to mean that they can hire one from you, it doesn't sound like you are offering one at all.

I think you simply need to say that "cycle hire is available" and not be overly concerned with articles. The general understanding is that, when someone offers hire of something like a bicycle, there will be a supply of them and you can only take what is available. There would be no assumption that you always receive the same bicycle.

Also, I'm not clear if the two tours you mention are exclusively for cyclists, or if that is just an option. It is also unclear from the information you gave if the two tours be individually booked, or if they are booked together. You should make this clear before offering cycle hire, as saying "cycle hire is available for both tours" could sound like you can only hire a bike if you're doing both.